# Looking for a method to replace a string with a hyperlink

Tags: c#, asp.net, hyperlink

I have a usercontrol in an asp web forms application that I am working on in C#.

I am binding to a repeater and outputting a field of information, named "Text", using the following syntax:

```
<%# DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "Text") %>
```

I am looking for a method that will allow my to search for a keyword within the string that is returned from above, and replace that string with a hyperlink such as

`<a href="www.anysite.com/keyword">keyword</a>`.

I'm not very familiar with user controls and getting data back in this manner so I am looking for advice on how this might be best handled.

Thanks!

Comment: Are you using the User Control within a Repeater or the User Control itself is using a Repeater?

Comment: The user control itself is using the repeater.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Hook into the [Repeater's OnItemDataBound](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.repeater.onitemdatabound.aspx) event.

The example on the linked documentation page does almost exactly what you want to do - it finds a label control in the item and updates the text.  You should be able to modify it from there to do a string find/replace.

Comment: Thanks for the link Womp. That was excatly what I was looking for!

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to use the OnItemDataBound event to check the value before you display it to the user.

Create a new method in your codebehind and set the OnItemDataBound="newmethod" so everytime an item gets bound it will call the method. Then in the method you check the data and if it needs to be change to a hyperlink you can change it at that time.